# Non-standard port with aliases

Tags: drush

I'm running Drush 9.5.2.

I set up a site alias. Drush recognizes it, but it will not connect via SSH. I get the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host mysite.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

The server doesn't use port 22. It uses port 2234.

My SSH config is set to use port 2234. I can SSH in if Drush isn't involved. There's nothing in the docs that addresses this. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes you can specify ssh port in the options part of the alias definition. I’m on my phone so I don’t have an example on hand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an alias that looks something like one of the examples below:

**Drush 9 Example:** ~/.drush/sites/my-site.yml

```
live:
  uri: example.com
  host: isp.net
  user: www-admin
  paths:
    drush-script: /path/to/drush
  ssh:
    options: '-p 2222 -o "AddressFamily inet"'
    tty: false
```

**Drush 8 Example** ~/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php

```
$aliases["my-site.live"] = array (
  'uri' => 'example.com',
  'remote-host' => 'isp.net',
  'remote-user' => 'www-admin',
  'ssh-options' => '-p 2234 -o "AddressFamily inet"',
  'path-aliases' => 
    array (
      '%drush-script' => '/path/to/drush',
    ),
);
```

Adjust 'ssh-options' as necessary for your configuration.

You may omit 'path-aliases' entirely if Drush is in your $PATH on the remote machine. Defining the Drush path is safer, though; the rules Bash follows for sourcing resource files for login shells vs. non-login shells et. al. is somewhat confusing.

Comment: That worked. Thank you! Follow up: where did you get that? I searched high and low on https://docs.drush.org and found nothing.

Comment: Drush 9 still needs better docs for sure.